# Quickly define TS type from JS object with named properties

Tags: typescript

Here is some JS code:

```
class Family {
    makePerson(n: string, a: number) {
        return {   // Want to define TS type here.
            name: n,
            age: a
        };
    }

    printPerson(p) { // Want to annotate "p" as type defined inside makePerson.
        console.log("name=" + p.name);
        console.log("address=" + p.address); // TS should warn here
    }
}

function main() {
    let f = new Family();
    let p = f.makePerson("Bart", 11);
    f.printPerson(p);
}
```

How can I use TypeScript to quickly define a type in function makePerson, so I get a useful warning in function printPerson.

By "quickly" I mean without having to re-specify the property names "name" and "age" that are already implicitly part of the JS object.  For example, some syntax like the following would be ideal:

```
// Suggested (not real) TypeScript system to define types from JS objects with properties.
makePerson(n: string, a: number) :Person { // I want TS to define "Person" type by examining function body.
    return {   // Want to define TS type here.
        name: n,
        age: a
    };
}
```

Comment: Does `type Person = ReturnType<typeof makePerson>` do what you want?

Comment: I didn't know about ReturnType.  It looks very useful.   In my real use-case the function makePerson is actually a class method in my class.  How can I use ReturnType in this case?

Comment: kaya3: I changed the JS code in my question to embed makePerson in class Family.  After experimenting I see that if I make makePerson a *static* function then I can use `type Person = ReturnType<typeof Family.makePerson>`.  As a bonus I can define the Person type before declaring the class, so I can use Person inside other class functions.   This answers my original question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kaya3 for telling me about ReturnType, I see the following method of using a static function in ReturnType works.  For example...

```
type Person = ReturnType<typeof Family.makePersonS>

class Family {
    makePerson(n: string, a: number): Person {
        return Family.makePersonS(n, a);
    }

    static makePersonS(n: string, a: number) {
        return {
            name: n,
            age: a
        };
    }

    printPerson(p: Person) {
        console.log("name=" + p.name);
        console.log("address=" + p.address); // TS warns here, as we wanted
    }
}

function main() {
    let f = new Family();
    let p = f.makePerson("Bart", 11);
    f.printPerson(p);
}
```

Comment: If it's not static, then you can use `ReturnType<Family['makePerson']>` without `typeof`. Note that indexed access types (where the left side `Family` must be a type, not a variable name) are written with square brackets, not dots.